# When using newCachedThreadPool how do I get the current number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to log the number of active threads created by a newCachedThreadPool call. I can't seem to find out where to get this value though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `ThreadFactory` to `newCachedThreadPool`
Let it implement some logging when creating a new Thread, since newCachedThreadPool reuses threads you don't have to worry about threads end.

OR

Cast the executor into a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and call its `getPoolSize()` method

Comment: The cached thread pool will end threads that have not been used recently.  Therefore, the custom `ThreadFactory` can only keep track of how many threads have been created not how many are active.

Comment: Be aware that casting the `ExectuorService` returned by `newCachedThreadPool` is not guaranteed to by a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in all implementations of Java.  With that being said, that may very well be a risk that you are willing to take.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are interested in the number of *threads* that exist or whether you are interested in the number of *tasks* that are active.  If you are interested in the tasks, then you can store a `Future` for each task that has been added.  When you want to know how many tasks are active, you can simply count the number of `Future` objects that respond `false` to `isDone`.  The ones that respond `true` can obviously be removed at that point.